# Inconsistent seccomp behavior

Tags: java, linux-kernel, ld-preload, seccomp

I am working on containing different applications using Linux's seccomp and I got to an inconsistency I cannot explain.

I have tried to give you examples clear enough to reproduce the problem.

I am creating a "protector module" which disallows process calling `set_robust_list` (for the sake of demoing the problem). Then I run processes where I inject this "protector module" using LD_PRELOAD and expect the process to stop when this system call is made.

I am making a shared object based on this code:

```
#include <seccomp.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>

static void  __attribute__((constructor))  Initialization(void) {
   scmp_filter_ctx ctx;
   prctl(PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS, 1);
   ctx = seccomp_init(SCMP_ACT_ALLOW); 
   seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_KILL, SCMP_SYS(set_robust_list), 0);
   seccomp_load(ctx);
}
```

I am building it with `gcc -shared seccompdemo.c -lseccomp -o libseccompdemo.so`.

Then to test it I'm building this executable:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE       
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>  

int main() {
   syscall(SYS_set_robust_list,0,0);
   return 0;
}
```

I'm building this with `gcc set_robust_list.c -o set_robust_list`.

Then **as expected** I'm runninig this executable with the above so and it gets killed with a signal:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=./libseccompdemo.so ./set_robust_list
Bad system call (core dumped)
```

The problem is when I'm trying to do the same trick with Java.

I'm invoking the same "protector module" on java it **does not seem to work** despite I know Java is calling `set_robust_list` from strace:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=./libseccompdemo.so java FileWriterTest /tmp/hosts < /etc/hosts
$ echo $?
0
```

See the strace output proves that java is calling 'set_robust_list':

```
$ strace -f java FileWriterTest /tmp/hosts < /etc/hosts 2>&1 | grep set_robust_list
set_robust_list(0x7f0b168af660, 24)     = 0
[pid 12847] set_robust_list(0x7f0b168ad9e0, 24 <unfinished ...>
[pid 12847] <... set_robust_list resumed> ) = 0
[pid 12848] set_robust_list(0x7f0b12b259e0, 24) = 0
```

I do see that java calls `clone` system call essentially for creating threads. I thought maybe seccomp filters are not inherited, but according to the documentation they are.

**I'd be very glad if someone could explain me why this is not working.**

For reference here is the Java code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileWriterTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        try {
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(args[0]);
            f.write(System.in.readAllBytes());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.format("Caught exception: "+e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `Bad system call (core dumped)` message is your shell telling you that the child process exited due to a `SIGSYS` signal. But if `SIGSYS` is blocked, the system call would just return an error, which would be handled in an application-specific manner.

I guess that `pthread_create` blocks signals while executing and therefore `set_robust_list` is only called with `SIGSYS` blocked, unlike your example code which doesn't modify the signal mask.

Anyways, it shouldn't really affect what you're trying to accomplish: Add a `System.out.println("Hello from Java!");` to your java `main` and you will see it won't print if you preload the segcomp filters, because `main` is never called as expected.